# Django-OpenCV: img is None in views and I cannot save modified img

Tags: python, django, opencv

Img is None and `cv2.imwrite()` doesn't work. How to correct this?

Also PyCharm displays:

> "Cannot find reference 'imread' in `__init__.py`"

and

> "Cannot find reference 'imwrite' in **init**.py".

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    img = cv2.imread(static('blog' + os.sep + 'misdyxcgAo4.jpg'), 0)
    print static('blog' + os.sep + 'misdyxcgAo4.jpg')
    print img
    cv2.imwrite(static('blog' + os.sep + 'messigray.png', img))
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Comment: what you get with `static()` ? url ? `imread()` can't read from url.

Comment: Replaced `img = cv2.imread('misdyxcgAo4.jpg', 0)` and there is a picture in a folder "blog", but still None.

Comment: try full path to image - it may run in different folder than you expect.

Comment: Wrote `img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Django\mysite\blog\misdyxcgAo4.jpg', 0)`, and and seemed all makes, but picture doesn't save (

Comment: did you use full path in `imwrite` ? It doesn't use url.

Comment: Oh, everything worked out, thanks! Also replaced url in `imwrite`.

Comment: furas, tell me please, write such code in `views` - is that normal?

Comment: `views` is place for modify data.